# Muhurtha for Auspicious Ceremonies

Tags: astrology

When a day selected for any auspicious work fulfils in full all the auspicious elements in a Muhurtha e.g strong lagna, tithi, vara, nakshatra, yoga and karana, + auspicious Tarabala, Chandrabala & Panchanga, zodiac but the vakya almanac shows Marana Yoga ( as opposed to the other Yoga mentioned which indicates Vishikambha), will this Marana Yoga make the Muhurtha totally inauspicious.

Many learned scholars say the above mentioned Marana Yoga doest have much negative influence and thus need not to be overly worried about.

Please comment with detail expiations when a Marana Yoga must take precedence?

Comment: I just wanted to say that Vakya Panchangam uses out of date astronomical information.  See my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/958/36