# What is Rahu kaala?

Tags: navagraha

According to Puranas, Rahu and Ketu don't have corresponding planets, but manifest during Grahana(eclipse). If this is the case,

- What is Rahu Kaala?
- How is the effect of Rahu felt during this time?

Comment: Rahu and ketu are chaya Grahas(the shadow planets), they are exactly at 180 degress to each other, they exist without grahana (eclipse) . For proof see any panchangam you will see the locations of rahu and it is written in panchangam adding 6 rashees to rahu makes ketu (1 rashee = 30 degrees ). For more details on calculation or rashi etc use this http://www.maharishiyagya.org/jyotish/rashis.html

Comment: @Yogi Thanks, but the link doesn't work. Can you repost the working link? So it appears that Rahu and Ketu are like shadows in the dark in the physical space having a complex but mathematically definable relationship with the visible grahas wrt their position in physical space? Also, the puranas are misleading in their definition of Rahu and Ketu equating them to asuras. I have heard from some advanced sadhakas that Rahu is Ganapathy and Ketu is Parvathy. I don't know how this fact weights in with regards to inauspiciousness of Rahu kaala, because Ganapathi is invoked before every undertaking.

Comment: Also please write or point me to a source which talks about Vakya Panchangam and the concept of athicharam(faster than average movement of planet) and how it must be factored in assessing a person's horoscope?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rahu (read first para or intro)puranas are not misleading they have their own version for every scientific fact. There is no written proof in scriptures that Raahu is ganapti and ketu is paarvati. See this answer for those tamil terms of panchangam http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-is-the-panchang-to-be-used-when-generating-a-horoscope also http://www.astroved.com/blogs/the-mysterious-ketu-and-powerful-ganesha

Comment: @Naveen "So it appears that Rahu and Ketu are like shadows in the dark in the physical space having a complex but mathematically definable relationship with the visible grahas wrt their position in physical space?"  Yes, except I'd take out the "complex" part.  The locations of Rahu and Ketu simply correspond to the lunar nodes, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7099/36 So it's easy to calculate the position of Rahu, but I'm still not sure what the connection is between the position of Rahu and Rahu Kalam.

Comment: Naveen and @Yogi It may interest you to know that in addition to Rahu and Ketu, there are nine more "shadow planets" called Upagrahas, most famously Gulika: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upagraha Unlike Rahu and Ketu, which are at least related to positions of the lunar nodes, the positions of the nine Upagrahas are just calculated mathematically.  I'm not sure if they have any basis in astronomical phenomena.

Answer (score 3):

Rahu kaalam is a calculated time of that day (unique & applicable to each day), considered to be unaustipious time for doing any religious activity.  Muhurta is calculated generally for religious activities relating to do good to the society.  Primarily muhurta is arrived to know about planetary positions to ensure that they are in proper state/position to accept offerings made during puja or religious ceremonies.

With changing times, instead of religious activities, it has become fashion to apply those principles to individuals for joining a new job or starting a new work...etc..

Being defined as unauspicious, work started or initiated during this period are generally considered unsuccessful.   Unfortunately, know few people approach jyotish for fixing muhurta for taking bribes (real, no jokes).

However, for doinig regular work there is no need for muhurta.

Comment: Can you explain how the Rahu and Ketu timings are calculated in the panchangam? My conception is without any direct or indirect relationship with visible planets(like eclipse time for instance) Rahu and Ketu timings cannot be calculated. If this is not the case the initial timing reference of Rahu and Ketu must have been given by the Rishis(without giving the relationship with visible planets) and we have been adding some constant number to update timings as days progress. If the former is the case, It this relationship of Rahu and Ketu with other visible planets that I'm seeking to know.