# What is the difference between Planet and nakshatra in astrology?

Tags: astrology

I head that Planets and nakshatra's are entirely different things in [Indian astrology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_astrology). Is that right? But I think in modern [astronomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomy) (science), Planet and nakshatra are related. Can anyone tell how Planet and nakshatra are related to or different from each other?

Comment: Namaste Star = English term (often used in astronomy)
Nakshatra = Hindu term (often used in vedic astrology) Conclusion = NO difference.

Comment: @Annonymous Sorry i have edited my question, i think you dot get what i mean, i am asking about Planet and nakshatra

Comment: Planet is a celestial body which revolves around a Star.
A nakshatra is a constellation, meaning a group of stars (those appear to be as a group from earth)

Comment: how nakshatra is calculating in indian astronomy

Comment: @Sree You can find some info on calculating Nakshatra in Indian Astronomy in answer at http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7738/1018

Comment: @ShreemayPanhalkar, that definition of planet is modern scientific. Graha is not same as planet, it means 'place' or 'house', because Sun and moon are part of nava-grahas. I'm not sure if Sree is asking about grahas or planets though.

Comment: @ram i am asking about the difference between grahas(planet) and nakshatra in astronomy. For example in planet system we have Moon(chandra) and that also in astronomy is both are same ?

Answer (score 1):

Nakshatras are 27 (or 28) divisions of sky. They correspond to the space the moon travels in one day. That's why they are called lunar mansions. They each have a type of Shakti, that corresponds to the God it is associated with. Look at the Wikipedia article for more info on nakshatras. The planets are the planets in orbit. Vedic astrology considers the sun, moon, mars, mercury, jupiter, venus, and saturn to be the main planets. There are also two nonphysical planets, Rahu and Ketu. Please read more about Vedic astrology.

Answer (score 1):

Astrology considers seven planets Sun, Moon, Mercury, Mars, Venus, Jupiter, Saturn and two nodes Rahu and Ketu. Since astrology is study of planetary influence viewing them from earth constellation or Zodiac becomes reference frame. Each constellation consists of group of stars called Nakshatra.

In Vedic astrology Moon sign is calculated based on Moon transition through different constellation, so based on placement of Moon on a particular nakshatra Moon sign will be calculated.

Please read our article "[Zodiac - Frame of Reference in Astrology](https://www.innovativeastrosolutions.com/single-post/2014/04/04/Zodiac---Frame-of-Reference-in-Astrology)" for more understanding

Comment: Overt self promotion is considered as spam. Please remove links of your site or your answer will be deleted.

Comment: Don't try to advertise your site. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) and also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way) posts.

Comment: what do you mean by planets?